# Getting value of dropdown laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have two selects (dropdowns), the second one is populated based on the first one with ajax. Now I want that when I select an option from the second one to display the detail or details of that value (or id). What I have done is display all the records of that column (`img_path`).

#### View

```
<div class="row">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="firstDropDown" name="selectCategory" onchange="change_category(this.value);">
                <option>Choose Category...</option>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category_name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="secondDropDown">
                <option>Choose Layer...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="gravataroverlay">
            <div id="gravatarsidebar">
            <img src="img/body.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
public function populateImages(){

    $input = Input::get('option');
    $maker = Layer::find($input);

    return Response::make($maker->get(array('id','img_path')));
}
```

#### Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#secondDropDown').change(function(){
        $.get("{{ url('populate/images')}}", 
            { option: $(this).val() }, 
            function(data) {
                var model = $('#gravatarsidebar');
                model.empty();

                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    //model.append("<option value='"+ element.id +"'>" + element.layer_name + "</option>");

                    model.append("<img src='img/"+ element.img_path +"' id='" +element.id+ "'>");
                });
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: You get the input by its name. On your first `<select name="selectCategory">` element, you would fetch it by using `Input::get('selectCategory');`

Comment: If i get it by its name it doesnt work. Thats why i use option. Dropdows work perfectly, what i doubt is ajax,